# C# Having Multiple Check and Radio check boxes and doing calculations based on which are checked?

Tags: c#, checkbox

Alright so doing just a quick code to get the idea of using check and radio boxes in my code. Here is what I have got so far ( at the bottom ). So, I figured I can just set up a string of if statements and starting with seeing if all 3 are checked, if not it would go through and see if the first one is checked if not ect. Though, it does kind of work for only checking one check box, when I checked all three it displays the final calculation. So in my case if I have had 3 checked, it would only display the Volt + NonExploding calculation making it show $50,100 instead of $51,600 for if it added it all up. Can I get some quick help as to what to do so it notices that all three are checked instead of just going to the final checked calculation? Thanks for the help, very much appreciated.

```
        private void button_Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Validating options 
        if (radioButton_ChevVolt.Checked || radioButton_FordPinto.Checked)
        {
            //no code needed
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Choose One of the Vehicles");
            return;
        }
        //Processing Input
        double SunRoof = 1000;
        double DVD = 500;
        double NonExploding = 100;
        double Volt = 50000;
        double Pinto = 1000;
        double TotalCost = 0;

        if (radioButton_ChevVolt.Checked)
                    {
                       TotalCost = Volt;
                       textBox_TotalCost.Text = TotalCost.ToString();
                    {
                    if (checkBox_SunRoof.Checked || checkBox_DVD.Checked || checkBox_NonExploding.Checked)
                    {
                       TotalCost = Volt + DVD + SunRoof + NonExploding;
                       textBox_TotalCost.Text = TotalCost.ToString();
                    }
                    if (checkBox_SunRoof.Checked)
                    {
                        TotalCost = Volt + SunRoof;
                        textBox_TotalCost.Text = TotalCost.ToString();
                    }
                    if (checkBox_DVD.Checked)
                    {
                        TotalCost = Volt + DVD;
                        textBox_TotalCost.Text = TotalCost.ToString();
                    }
                    if (checkBox_NonExploding.Checked)
                    {
                        TotalCost = Volt + NonExploding;
                        textBox_TotalCost.Text = TotalCost.ToString();
                    }


            }
        }



    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'd like to add, the reason I did not do the rest of the checkboxes is because I couldn't get the idea of getting all 3 noticed first. After this I will add in Volt + DVD + SunRoof and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code is doing is running all of the `if` statements - it's not just going to the final one. It's just that the final one is last so it appears that way.

Here's the easy fix:

```
        if (checkBox_SunRoof.Checked && checkBox_DVD.Checked && checkBox_NonExploding.Checked)
        {
            TotalCost = Volt + DVD + SunRoof + NonExploding;
            textBox_TotalCost.Text = TotalCost.ToString();
        }
        else if (checkBox_SunRoof.Checked)
        {
            TotalCost = Volt + SunRoof;
            textBox_TotalCost.Text = TotalCost.ToString();
        }
        else if (checkBox_DVD.Checked)
        {
            TotalCost = Volt + DVD;
            textBox_TotalCost.Text = TotalCost.ToString();
        }
        else if (checkBox_NonExploding.Checked)
        {
            TotalCost = Volt + NonExploding;
            textBox_TotalCost.Text = TotalCost.ToString();
        }
```

It also seems to me that the initial `||` should be `&&` to make this work.

I would also be inclined to look at this calculation using the ternary operator `?:`. Your code might look like this:

```
TotalCost += radioButton_ChevVolt.Checked ? Volt : 0.0;
TotalCost += checkBox_SunRoof.Checked ? SunRoof : 0.0;
TotalCost += checkBox_DVD.Checked ? DVD : 0.0;
TotalCost += checkBox_NonExploding.Checked ? NonExploding : 0.0;
textBox_TotalCost.Text = TotalCost.ToString();
```

And, finally, another hint. Don't use `double` for currency amounts as it is designed for scientific values. Use `decimal` instead.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the tips, it worked, I'll reply back if I have more trouble but don't think I will.